# Laravel passport api/user route is unauthorized

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js, axios, laravel-passport

Im using laravel passport for token authentication, and axios for send requests from vuejs frontend. I can successfully login usin `oauth/token` url and it does return access token, refresh token and other data. But when every time i trying to access `api/user` route it returns me unauthorized error message. It seems bearer token is not in header but i cannot insert that token to axios header in `bootstrap.js` it also return error. Can anyone help.

Comment: You did axios request correctly??

Comment: `axios.get('api/user').then( response => { })` there it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like ,first create an axios instance with token

```
const HTTP = axios.create({
  baseURL: `http://baseURL.com/api`,
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer {token}'
  }
})
```

Then you can use that 'HTTP' constant can be in your script to call the request

```
created() {
    HTTP.get(`user`)
    .then(response => {

    })
    .catch(e => {
      this.errors.push(e)
    })
  }
```

Refer more here to how to work with [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)

Comment: You can keep this first block of code as common js file and export if you wish , that could be better like don't want to repeat again

Comment: Than you. I'll try.

Comment: here created() is actually a hook in vuejs instant life cycle, check this out https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html